# How can I solve this connection problem with firebees?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-assistant

what the Solution for this problem

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hey @samy. Does this happen when you click the `Connect to Firebase` button? At that point the URL you see is supposed to be opened in the default browser of your system, but it looks like your system might not have a default browser set up. If might be worth checking: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been resolved